# How to disable default cursor style (text selector) when doing a custom click and drag in angular?

Tags: angularjs, mean-stack

I want to disable the default cursor style (cursor: text) when building a custom click and drag behaviour in angularjs. I've found ways to do this using the javascript events, by calling preventDefault() on the event, like so:

```
$(element).on('mousedown touchstart', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  mouseDown = true;
});
```

But how does this work when using the angular ng-mousedown event or other "ng-" events?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply access the event from ng-mousedown by passing `$event` as a parameter to the function you're calling, like so:

```
<div ng-mousedown="someFunction($event)">
```

And then call `preventDefault()`:

```
$scope. someFunction = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
}
```